# What is the purpose of base_to_quote_rate column in sales_flat_quote table?

Tags: magento-1.9

I don't know if there are more occurrences of `base_to_quote_rate` column in the database. But my question is:

**What is the purpose of `base_to_quote_rate column` in `sales_flat_quote table`?**

Answer (score 0):

There are legacy columns in Magento tables that no longer server any purpose.

Rather than searching the database, you can search the code for places where it is referenced and see if it is still relevant:

```
[searching for "BaseToQuoteRate"]
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php: * @method float getBaseToQuoteRate()
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php: * @method Mage_Sales_Model_Quote setBaseToQuoteRate(float $value)
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php:        $this->setBaseToQuoteRate($baseCurrency->getRate($quoteCurrency));

[searching for "base_to_quote_rate"]
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/wsdl.xml:                    <element name="base_to_quote_rate" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/wsi.xml:                    <xsd:element name="base_to_quote_rate" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="0"/>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Entity/Setup.php:                    'base_to_quote_rate'   => array('type'=>'static'),
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Recurring/Profile.php:            ->setBaseToOrderRate($this->getInfoValue('order_info', 'base_to_quote_rate'))
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Setup.php:                    'base_to_quote_rate'    => array('type'=>'static'),
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/doc/quote.txt:        base_to_quote_rate
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml:                <base_to_quote_rate>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml:                </base_to_quote_rate>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml:                    <to_quote>base_to_quote_rate</to_quote>
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php:    ->addColumn('base_to_quote_rate', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '12,4', array(
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-install-1.4.0.0.php:  `base_to_quote_rate` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.26-0.9.27.php:    $this->getTable('sales/quote'), 'base_to_quote_rate', 'decimal(12,4) NULL AFTER `store_to_quote_rate`'
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.26-0.9.27.php:$installer->addAttribute('quote', 'base_to_quote_rate', array('type'=>'static'));
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.30-0.9.31.php:$installer->getConnection()->modifyColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote'), 'base_to_quote_rate', 'decimal(12,4)');
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php:            'base_to_quote_rate' => array(
dev/tests/functional/tests/app/Mage/Checkout/Test/Fixture/Cart.xml:    <field name="base_to_quote_rate" is_required="0">
```